# Exibir dados do BD em forma de lista

Tags: php, html, mysql, sintaxe

Estou desenvolvendo um site para realizar doações/adoções de animais online, mas sou extremamente leigo no assunto e meu conhecimento em PHP é pequeno. Para o usuário doar um animal (adicionar um anúncio no site) ele terá que preencher um formulário contendo Título do anuncio, Descrição do anúncio e Imagem do animal (esses três dados serão salvos no banco de dados). Esta função já está funcionando, o problema é que eu não sei como mostrar esses dados na tela inicial do site. Eu sei que devo executar um comando "SELECT", mas não sei onde colocar esse comando, qual a sintaxe para inserir esse SELECT no PHP, e como inserir os dados do select dentro de uma variável para posteriormente mostrá-la na página inicial. Não preciso de nada mirabolante, apenas algo básico para mostrar a imagem na página inicial (lista de animais). Alguém poderia me ajudar? Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Como que executou o INSERT? é bem parecido. Está usando PDO? se não estiver recomendo fortemente. Qual versão do PHP? posta o que fez até o momento fica mais fácil ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','bd'); //configuração do bd
    $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT algo,algomais from tabela"); //prepara a query
    $sql->execute(); //executa a query
    $rs = $sql->get_result(); //pega o resultado da query
    while ($result = $rs->fetch_assoc() ) { //enquanto tiverem resultados correspondentes da query
        echo "Alguma coisa:".$result['algo']."Alguma coisa a mais".$result['algomais']; //lista os resultados
    }
?>
```

Não sei como você está fazendo seu site já que não especificou porém é muito recomendado a utilização de **MySQLi** ou **PDO** visto que comandos **mysql_*** se tornaram obsoletos no PHP 5.5.

O exemplo acima faz uso de MySQLi para listar algo e algomais no site usando o echo php